# How do you properly "reset" a <select> element that supports multiple options in regular JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to reset `<select>` tags by themselves instead of making them reset with the entire form. This is what I have so far:

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
    <select id="s" name="select" multiple>
        <option disabled>Select a value!</option>
        <option value="one">1</option>
        <option value="two">2</option>
        <option value="three">3</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="resetS()" type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

And the JS:

```js
function resetS() {
    const selectedOptions = document.getElementById('s').selectedOptions;
    for (let i = 0; i < selectedOptions.length; i++) {
        selectedOptions[i].selected = false;
    }
}
```

When I first tried this, it seemed to work. *However*, only when *one* option is selected. I've noticed that when there is more than one option currently selected, it seems to break.

[image]

Starting with three options, and clicking the `Reset` button results in this, for some reason:

[image]

Every option gets deselected *apart from one*. Why does this happen?
Clicking the `Reset` button again deselects the one still selected option though.

Comment: I'm not sure, and it's not clear from the spec, but it's possible that the list is a "live" list of elements. Thus an indexed `for` loop like you have won't work, because each time you un-set the `selected` flag, the list actively changes, and your loop will thus skip an element. You might try using a `while` loop that tests the length to be > 0 and unset the `selected` flag on the first element on each iteration.

Comment: Re-checked the spec, and I think that's the issue. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) attribute to `-1` to indicate that no element is selected.

```js
function resetS() {
    const multipleSelect = document.getElementById('s');
    multipleSelect.selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

```html
<form autocomplete="off">
    <select id="s" name="select" multiple>
        <option disabled>Select a value!</option>
        <option value="one">1</option>
        <option value="two">2</option>
        <option value="three">3</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="resetS()" type="button">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Comment: He's got a multi-select element; `selectedIndex` doesn't make sense for those.

Comment: @Pointy according to [the definition](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp), `selectedIndex` returns the index of the first option selected on a multiple select

Comment: from your snippet it appears that you're correct, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

The list of selected `<option>` elements is a "live" list. When you change the `selected` flag on one of the elements, the list changes; that is, the `<option>` you changed *disappears* from the list, so the length gets 1 shorter. An indexed `for` loop will therefore skip elements.

The way to deal with that (well, one way) is to use a `while` loop as follows:

```
function resetS() {
    const selectedOptions = document.getElementById('s').selectedOptions;
    while (selectedOptions.length) {
        selectedOptions[0].selected = false;
    }
}
```

*edit* — or you could use the method suggested in Tom's answer, which is simpler.

Comment: It being a "live" list makes a lot of sense. I didn't see that when looking for clues myself.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still has this problem, this is the best way to clear items:

```
choices_element.removeActiveItems();
```

https://github.com/Choices-js/Choices/issues/606#issuecomment-1165557774